# Devise Gem rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the devise gem to build signin/signout for users. Following this tutorial http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise/, it was working all the way until I ran rake db:migrate.

```
    rails g devise user
    rake db:migrate
```

I ran into the error

```
    rake aborted!
    Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'
```

I managed to clear the previous error involving

```
    require': cannot load such file -- devise/orm/false (LoadError)
```

by changing false to "active_record" in app/config/initializers/devise.rb and that worked for me

```
    require 'devise/orm/active_record'
```

The problem now is I can't make a migration through devise. Does anyone know to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with your gems.

Try `bundle update` or remove Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` again.